# 3 Level List Comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How does this three deep list comprehension work? Specifically, how is `house` within scope of `bisect.bisect(heaters, house)`? My understanding of generators is that they execute in order from left to right and that piece of code is to the left of where `house` is created. Bonus: if you can rewrite this using for loops.

```
import bisect
houses, heaters = [1,2,3,90, 4],[1,4]

max(min(abs(house - heater)
   for i in [bisect.bisect(heaters, house)]
   for heater in heaters[i-(i>0):i+1])
for house in houses)
```

Comment: They’re left to right in the same generator expression, but `for house in houses` and `for i in […] for heater in heaters[…]` are two different generator expressions (note the parenthesis at the end of line 6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression has two different generator expressions. One is inside `max` and has one `for` clause. The other is nested inside the first one, in the `min` calls, and has two `for` clauses. The indentation of your current code sort of shows the relationship with its indentation, but it could be more explicit:

```
max(
    min(
        abs(house - heater)
        for i in [bisect.bisect(heaters, house)]
        for heater in heaters[i-(i>0):i+1]
    )
    for house in houses
)
```

Here you can see the nested structure: `max(... for house in houses)` is the outer generator comprehension, while `min(abs(house-heater) for i in ... for heater in ...)` is the inner one.

The inner generator expression can refer to the iterator variable `house` from the outer generator expression (just like the function call `f(x)` in `(f(x) for x in iterable)` refers to `x`).

Comment: Add a comment: the for i in [bisect] is a for loop over a single integer

Comment: Yeah, that's a very sneaky way to get an assignment to a local variable inside a generator expression. it's useful since `i` gets used several times in the main `for` clause afterwards.

Comment: Yeah it is doing something i wouldn't otherwise know how to do, except for with the new := PEP.

Comment: Evan, could you link to what you're referencing?

Answer (score 1):

Rewritten using `for` loops for bonus points.

```
import bisect
houses, heaters = [1,2,3,90, 4],[1,4]


def loop1():
    for house in houses:
        def loop2():
            for i in [bisect.bisect(heaters, house)]:
                for heater in heaters[i-(i>0):i+1]:
                    yield abs(house - heater)
        yield min(loop2())


max(loop1())
```

Comment: Rather than the `for i` loop, you can just do `i = bisect.bisect(...)`. The `for` loop is only needed in the generator expression since you can't otherwise do assignments (at least, not until PEP 572 gets implemented for Python 3.8).

Comment: @Blckknght upvoted your comment because that is an important point, but the question was about how the comprehensions could possibly work, rather than how it outght to be done, so I left it in to make that easier to see.

Comment: Yeah, the regular loop for the assignment works fine. I just wanted to mention it, since the only reason to avoid a regular assignment is because you can't do one in a generator expression.